# invisible recaptcha - how to programmatically bind to a button?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

Has anyone succeeded in doing so?

[Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#explicit_render) is very unclear about binding to a button in runtime. It just says:

> Deferring the binding can be achieved by specifying your onload
>   callback function and adding parameters to the JavaScript resource.

And that's it. No actual instructions on how to bind it to a button-element programmatically.

PS. I cannot use "automatic binding" since there's some logic involved - should I have recaptcha or not.

Comment: dont know what you are asking, what u mean by "bind to a button" ?

Comment: @johnSmith That's how invisible recaptcha work - by being bound to a button. Check the docs https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#explicit_render See, it says `Programmatically bind the challenge to a button`

Comment: yeah there is even an example that is absolutely the same as my answer  I just left out the validate function in between. that is `Programmatically bound` you write a little programm that says onclick initialize the captcha and thats it

Comment: and what google means by `bind the challenge to a button` is, that you click a button and the challenge gets started. It doesnt need to be bound to a button, you can call `grecaptcha.execute()` whenever you like

Comment: Hi @jazzcat, I have the exact same issue. Have you been able to bind the challenge to a button and have it execute automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Googledocs seem to be very clear

```
document.getElementById('yourbutton').onclick = function(e){
   grecaptcha.execute();
}
```

also googledocs is very clear that you have to use a div

> Invoking the reCAPTCHA verification programmatically can be achieved
>   by rendering the challenge in a div

```
<div class="g-recaptcha"
      data-sitekey="your_site_key"
      data-callback="onSubmit"
      data-size="invisible">
</div>
```

Comment: This is will invoke the challenge programmatically. Not bind to a button.

Comment: thats absolutely the same thing! the binding to the button is done programattically. just put the code i posted to the place when your "logic" finished

Comment: Yes, that's what I have right now.

See, the "normal" recaptcha shows you a simple checkbox you need to click. And Google then verifies your browser activity (how "natural" 
 are the mouse moves, google-cookies etc.). The *invisible* recaptcha just offers you to click a `<button>` instead of this checkbox. And performs all the same checks.

While `grecaptcha.execute()` just shows you the "select street signs". Always. It does not analyse your mouse moves. Tested several dozen times before asking the question...

Comment: ok thats all fine, but could you also mention what you try to achieve or how you expect it to behave? or at least what problems you encounter?  add that to your question `programmatically bind to a button?` is way too broad

Comment: By default Google binds Recaptcha to all elements that have `class=g-recaptcha`. I need to bind recaptcha at runtime programmatically.

Comment: if you add `data-size="invisible"` the captcha will be bound when execute() is called, not in before and you can call that at anytime of runtime. So whats your actual problem as the solution provided by google is exactly what you are asking for??

Comment: If anyone knows how to solve this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66378905/call-back-with-recaptcha-ruby-rails, it would be appreciated.